Подскажите пожалуйста как создать ограничение вывода символов в get_post на wordpress
есть вот такой код который лежит в functions а вывод происходит через randomPosts(); подскажите пожалуйста как в этом месте echo get_post()->post_content; ограничить кооличество вывода символов необходимо чтобы выводилась не вся новость а только ее часть...


function randomPosts() {
query_posts('orderby=rand&showposts=10tag=auto');
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="random-post">
    <div class="random-post_img"><a title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a></div>
    <div class="random-post_body">
        <ul>
            <li><a title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
            <li><?php echo get_post()->post_content; ?></li>
            <li><div class="random-post_author"><a title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_author(); ?></a></div></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; endif;
}




Мне помог этот код решить мою задачу 

Я не знаю правильно ли это может кто то подскажет иначе

Опубликуй решение ответом, а не комментом. Потом отметишь его как решение. Это может помочь другим.

Я решил задачу таким образом - просто заменил эту строку:
<?php echo get_post()->post_content; ?>

на вот эту:
<?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 20, '...' ); ?>

где 20 - это сокращение новости по количеству слов.
таким образом, мой код выглядит сейчас так, в functions вставляю этот код:
 /**
 * Вывод 10 записей новостей на главной странице
 *
 */

function randomPosts() {
query_posts('orderby=rand&showposts=10tag=auto');
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="random-post">
    <div class="random-post_img"><a title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a></div>
    <div class="random-post_body">
        <ul>
            <li><a title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
            <li><?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 20, '...' ); ?></li>
            <li><div class="random-post_author"><a title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_author(); ?></a></div></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; endif;
}

а там, где необходимо вывести, например, на главной, вставляю этот код:
<?php randomPosts(); ?>

